# How to get the name of the header in GWT celltable

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

Im working on a application in which the user has a GWT Celltable and when the column header is clicked, the name of the column should be displayed as a window alert. I checked out many tutorials but haven't found the solution. Please suggest me if there is any click handler function to get the name of the column by clicking on the header in GWT Celltable.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onPreviewColumnSortEvent` for a column header and call `getValue()` on the header to get the text of the header.

Comment: Hi, I have tried as mentioned in the following link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175410/getting-header-column-names-in-cell-table-on-click-in-gwt]. But I haven't got the desired output.

Comment: Show your code. If you don't need to pass a custom handler, it can be simplified - you can call a method to show the text right inside the onBrowserEvent().